# Vnc / rdp grey screen

Tags: settings

Ive been trying to get vnc or rdp working. Ive installed vncserver, and I can connect fine. But when I do all I get is a blank grey screen. Any ideas what Im missing? Or is there another prefered rdp/vnc setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered nomachine? https://www.nomachine.com

It is my go to for setting up screen share on computers. It works on Linux,  Mac,  Windows and requires almost no setup. Also lets you hear audio from the remote system.  If you prefer open source there is OpenNX,  same tech as nomachine,  but for easy of setup,  I just use nomachine.

Comment: This works like a charm. Now the only problem is I cant get my resolution to exceed 800x600. This is hosted in hyper v though so i dont know if there is going to be a soultion for that.